# Flutter Giving error in running the test app

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

It would be great if someone could help me out.
I am trying to learn it and these errors are stoping me.

```
Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\flutternew\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
 Configure project :app
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 27 in C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 27 not accepted.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\flutternew\android\build.gradle' line: 24
 What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
        platforms;android-27 Android SDK Platform 27
     To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
     Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 7m 38s
  Command: C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\flutternew\android\gradlew.bat app:properties
Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

Comment: have you tried with an iOS device?

Comment: did u install the sdk required in sdk manager?

Comment: Please post the output of `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: It seems like a gradle issue, maybe changing it to -dev branch would work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the logs, this is the cause - `Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 27 not accepted.`

You can run `flutter doctor` from a terminal, and it ask you to run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` in order to accept them. Fix any other issues it may indicate. After that, you should be good to go.